# QML OnHighligt movement completed

Tags: qt, qml

I have this ListView:

```
ListView {
    id: topList
    focus: true
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    preferredHighlightBegin: height - 70
    preferredHighlightEnd: height
    highlightMoveSpeed: 150
    highlight: Rectangle { width: theListView.width; height: 22; color: "yellow" }
    highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
}
```

Now, when I use up or down arrow the list moves nice and fine. However, when the movement is done, I would like to trigger another animation. Have tried listening on onMovementEnded and onFlickEnded but neither of them seems to be triggered when the animation is done.

Answer (score 1):

The QtQuick examples include an example of rolling your own: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/declarative-modelviews-listview-highlight-qml.html

The basic idea is to prevent the view from moving the highlight itself:

```
highlightFollowsCurrentItem: false
```

and use an animation to make the highlight follow the currentItem.  You will probably want to stick to SmoothedAnimation or SpringAnimation since they handle the target position being moved before the animation is complete.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not possible. `highlightPosAnimator` and `highlightSizeAnimator` are part of `QDeclarativeListView` private implementation, and not accesible by "user" code.

If you need custom/combined highlight animation, looks like you have to roll your own.